# Варианты записи названий автомобилей в обычной разговорной речи

Tags: орфография, ономастика, правила

Какой из вариантов правильный?

1. У меня будет вольво.
2. У меня будет "вольво".
3. У меня будет "Вольво".

Различается ли правило написания названий автомобилей в предложениях такой же структуры при словах "волга" и "джип"?

Answer (score 4):

Если имеется в виду марка  автомобиля, то  в кавычках с прописной буквы: автомобили «Волга», «Вольво», «Ниссан», «Шкода», если сам автомобиль как изделие – со строчной буквы в кавычках (кроме названий, совпадающих с собственными именами – личными и географическими). Например:"вольво", «кадиллак», «москвич», «тойота», «ниссан», но: «Волга», «Ока» (совпадают с именами собственными, поэтому пишутся с большой буквы).

Исключения: «жигули», «мерседес» (совпадают с именами собственными, но пишутся со строчной).

Однако на практике различить, в каком случае наименование представляет собой название марки автомобиля, а в каком – наименование технического изделия, часто представляется затруднительным: Всем автомобилям он предпочитает «Тойоту» / «тойоту». В спорных случаях решение о написании с прописной или строчной буквы принимает автор текста.

• Названия, написанные латиницей, в кавычки не заключаются: автомобили Toyota Yaris, Peugeot 306, Daewoo Matiz, Škoda Fabia, Lada Priora.

• Неоднословные названия (марка и модель автомобиля), написанные кириллицей, пишутся через дефис, при этом все части наименования пишутся с прописной буквы: «Лада-Приора», «Тойота-Королла», «Рено-Меган», «Ниссан-Теана», «Хёндай-Гетц», «Ниссан-Альмера-Классик», «Сузуки-Гранд-Витара». Но: «Фольксваген-жук» (перекличка с нарицательным существительным).

• Аббревиатурные названия пишутся без кавычек: ЗИЛ, ВАЗ, КамАЗ.

• В бытовом употреблении названия средств передвижения пишутся без кавычек, например: Приехал на стареньком москвиче (на роскошном кадиллаке, на джипе).

Без кавычек пишутся также разговорные названия машин с уменьшительно-ласкательными суффиксами, напр.: москвичок, фордик, уазик.

А вот вариант "У меня будет вольво" может предполагать и марку, и изделие,судить  и выбирать автору. По крайней мере здесь нет разговорного оттенка, упрощения, я бы написала  со строчной (маленькой) буквы и в кавычках

https://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/kavychki-gospoda-kavychki.html